# c# Method redirect or overload (possibly with arguments)

Tags: c#, function, redirect, methods, overloading

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm essentially looking for a class constructor redirect.

An example of what I'm attempting:

```
    public class Test
    {
        public Test() : TestFromOther();
        //public Test() => TestFromOther();    
        public TestFromOther() { return 'this' with some stuff done here }
        //another case might be => TestFromOther(defaultparam)
    }
```

I'm trying to do this so that even if the base constructor is called, it redirects to my method.

(I don't want to just put a call to TestFromOther() inside the body of the constructor.. I'm specifically looking for the `:TestFromOther()` or `=>` operator.. I've seen it before but for the life of me cannot remember how it's done)

EDIT: It's mostly for cleanliness and readability, thus having the Logger.GetCurrentClassLogger();

```
public class Logger {
    private string _callerClass;

    // obviously this doesn't function, but is the ideal end product
    //public Logger() => GetCurrentClassLogger();
    // Ideally I want the constructor to be this function and if a user, for
    // whatever reason does call the empty constructor, it goes to this func
    public Logger GetCurrentClassLogger() {
        StackFrame[] sf = new StackTrace().GetFrames();
        string callerName = "";
        foreach (StackFrame f in sf) {
            if (f == sf[0])
                continue;
            if (f.GetMethod().Name == ".ctor") {
                callerName = f.GetMethod().ReflectedType.Name;
                break;
                }
            callerName = f.GetMethod().Name;
            break;
            }
        this._callerClass = callerName;
        return this;
        }
    }
```

I trimmed this down about as far as I could for use as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "chain" constructors. it's not a redirection.

```
public class Test
{
    public Test() : this("defaultParam") {}
    public Test(string stringParam) { }
}
```

It will execute `Test(string stringParam)` first and then `Test()`

---

**Edit per the comments and the edited question**

`static` method is the way to achieve what you like:

```
public static Logger GetCurrentClassLogger() {...}
```

and the instantiation:

```
var logger = Logger.GetCurrentClassLogger(); // no new key word here
```

Comment: I get "Must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern or partial" when I attempt this.

Comment: This is close to what I had in mind, my problem is that the other method is trying to return an object `Test` but I can't return a new object from the `: this ("defaultParam") { }` function.. And I obviously can't do `this = Test("stringValue");` either.. Think of it as kind of like `new Object.FromOtherObject()`

Comment: That is true. Constructor don't return type. Their job is to initialize the current instance. Why would you want to return an object and not to initialize the fields in the current instance?

Comment: I'm not sure i'm following you...  try to edit your question and add a concrete and thorough example of the scenario

Comment: I did as you asked and pasted in a more concise version of what I'm attempting to do.. Maybe if I defined it as a static method that returned an instance of Logger?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146614/discussion-between-misternad-and-ofir-winegarten).

Comment: @MisterNad in that case a static method is the way to go.

Comment: Okay, I understand this.. But what to do about the empty constructor? If a user calls it then they just get a broken object.. Unless I have to code in a catch in the empty constructor to call the static method.. In which case, again, I cannot re-assign `this`.  Thanks for taking the time to respond, this has gone beyond what I originally asked.

Comment: Mark the constructor as private.

Comment: Idiotically, I'd never considered doing that..ever. Nice trick, thank you Ofir, your input is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. C# only allows you to call a base constructor or another constructor of the current class.

BTW the thing `TestFromOther` is also not a valid syntax, as it it is neither a method nor a constructor. Further, a constructor is not allowed to return anything.

The typical solution here would rather be to use a single constructor (possibly private such that it cannot be accessed from the outside) that does what you want. Or you may use helper methods for the initialization.